# pip.exe has stopped working

Tags: python, pip

I know this question has been asked a few times before, but none of the answers I've read have managed to solve my problem.

When I try to run any of the following, I get an error saying "pip.exe has stopped working:

- easy_install
- pip
- pip3

It was working for me previously (the last time I used it was probably a month ago), but not anymore. I'm using Python 3.4.4, I checked the PATH and it's configured correctly. Does anyone know what else might be causing the issue?

Comment: This sounds like Windows, have you changed your operating system?  Does python work OK otherwise?

Comment: I think it might be windows, but the OS hasn't changed. I had the same problem when I tried to run a "java -jar" command. Python is working fine besides the pip problem

Comment: Have you tried to execute it inside the command line if it prints out anything helpful?

Comment: I'm running it from the command line, but unfortunately it doesn't print out anything. I just get that popup that says "pip.exe" has stopped working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem before and the solution is quite simple.

First try updating pip via command:

pip install --upgrade pip

If that doesn't work try uninstalling current version of python and reinstalling the newest version.

Note1: Do not just delete install files and files in your C drive ,uninstall everything packages, everything that might cause problems, especially delete old python packages and extensions they might not work with the newest python version and that might be the problem. You can see in python website which packages and extensions are supported.

Note2: Do not and I repeat DO NOT install .msi or .exe extensions they don't work anymore always use .whl (wheel) files. If you have one .msi or .exe uninstall them form your system completely; that also means that you have to uninstall them from command prompt.

Note3: Always check if the .whl is compatible with your Python version.

Note4: Also don't forget to save your projects before doing anything.

Hope that works :D

Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Something that helped me was to deactivate the virtualenv and then initialize it again, and then I was able to continue working. I use conda.

```
conda deactivate myenv
conda activate env
```